# intentservice crashes due to bad internet connectivity

Tags: android, http-post, android-intentservice

I'm trying to send data via POST method in intent service. But the application crashes if the data connection(internet) is not good. I have been advised to use thread instead of intentservice becuz thread can handle multiple instance while sending data via POST method but intentservice can't. Please advice if I should use thread fully instead of IntentService or try thread for POST method inside IntentService. Thanks in advance. P.S. I've a timertask to start IntentService in my MainActivity to start service every 2 minutes.

```html
package com.example.anew;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.ParseException;

public class LocalService extends IntentService{
 
 String Sender, TimeStamp, Mesg, webResponse, value;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";

 public LocalService() {
  super("LocalService");
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
    if(c.getCount()==0){
     System.out.println("No SMS found");
              return;
    }
  
    else if(c.moveToFirst()){
           for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){             
               Sender = c.getString(1);
               TimeStamp = c.getString(2);
               Mesg = c.getString(3); 
               readWebPage(c.getString(0));  //POST method
               c.moveToNext();                 
           }           

       }

    c.close();
 }

 private void readWebPage(String id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
  value = settings.getString("code", "");
  
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/mail.asmx/send?"); 

  //Post Data
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
  nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", value));
  nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "IN"));
  nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source", Sender));
  nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", TimeStamp));
  nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", Mesg));

  //Encoding POST data
  try{
   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
  }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
   System.out.println(e);
  }

  //making POST request.
  try{
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
   String XmlString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
   XmlString=XmlString.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
   XmlString = XmlString.substring(XmlString.indexOf("[") + 1, XmlString.lastIndexOf("]"));
   JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(XmlString);
   webResponse = jObj.getString("status");
            System.out.println("Web Response:" + webResponse);
            
            if(webResponse.equals("ok")){
             
          if(id!=null){
           
                    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM student WHERE id="+id);
          }
          else{
              
                    System.out.println("No SMS found");
          }
             
        
             
            }


  }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  // Log exception
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // Log exception
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(e);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(e);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

  
 } // readWebPage ends
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use AsyncTask to send the data to the server and repeat or reschedule if it fails (if you need it).
An example here (I copied your code, but haven't tested it, still it should work) : https://gist.github.com/jacktech24/71a28047a8007cab1c50

Also if you need to do some network stuff after some time, it's good to use GcmNetworkManagers OneOffTask (if you have Google Play services available on target device, which is true if your app was installed from Play Store), you can find an example here https://github.com/jacktech24/gcmnetworkmanager-android-example

Comment: I heard that asynctask has something like 5 threadpool. suppose I've to send more than 5 data at a time, will it still be able to send data when there is bad network?

Comment: What do you mean by 5 data at a time?  Calling AsyncTask 5 times?

Comment: I mean my code retrieves rows from database and send via POST. It retrieves data till database gets empty and then send it. If network connectivity is not good and there are more than 5 data asynctask might not send all the data and then the intentservice will close. Would it be the case?